# Drop Down GUI matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, workspace

```
 function DoneButtonPushed(app, event)
            assignin('base','roll_no_GUI1',app.StudentInfoDropDown.Value);
            assignin('base','projname_GUI1',app.ProjectInfoDropDown.Value);
            assignin('base','roll_no_GUI2',app.StudentInfoDropDown_2.Value);
            assignin('base','projname_GUI2',app.ProjectInfoDropDown_2.Value);
            assignin('base','roll_no_GUI3',app.StudentInfoDropDown_3.Value);
            assignin('base','projname_GUI3',app.ProjectInfoDropDown_3.Value);
            assignin('base','roll_no_GUI4',app.StudentInfoDropDown_4.Value);
            assignin('base','projname_GUI4',app.ProjectInfoDropDown_4.Value);
            assignin('base','roll_no_GUI5',app.StudentInfoDropDown_5.Value);
            assignin('base','projname_GUI5',app.ProjectInfoDropDown_5.Value);
            closereq
        end
```

Hi, I am creating a GUI which contains DropDowns. They are 10 dropdowns as you can see from the code.  And I am using `assignin` to save each one of them into `base` workspace. But I would like to club all of them into a 2 char array's or 2 cell array's and send only two variables into the `base` workspace viz, `Roll_nos` and `Projnames_GUI`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two cell arrays and assign them in the base workspace:

```
roll_nos = {
  app.StudentInfoDropDown.Value,
  app.StudentInfoDropDown_2.Value,
  app.StudentInfoDropDown_3.Value,
  app.StudentInfoDropDown_4.Value,
  app.StudentInfoDropDown_5.Value
};

projnames_gui = {
  app.ProjectInfoDropDown.Value,
  app.ProjectInfoDropDown_2.Value,
  app.ProjectInfoDropDown_3.Value,
  app.ProjectInfoDropDown_4.Value,
  app.ProjectInfoDropDown_5.Value
};

assignin('base','Roll_nos',roll_nos)
assignin('base','Projnames_GUI',projnames_gui)
```